# How does a Rotary Encoder work without connecting it to 5V

Tags: encoder, 5v, rotary, how-does-it-work

Like in this picture:
[image]

I know we can hook 5v later externally to debounce but still, i heard it works without debounce circuit even if its *bouncy*. But how can it send signals if there are only output and gnd pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just mechanical contacts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKIqxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Encoder wired to micro-controller with internal pull-ups.*

The encoder is probably wired as shown (but I don't know why there are five wires on your diagram). What you can't see is that the internal pull-up resistors in the Arduino have to be enabled for this to work.

Comment: i think im getting this. So if the SW1 is open, the related pin is 1. But if the SW1 is closed, the pin is 0. Am i correct? There are rotary encoders in  the market which has a +5V, A, B, C pins like KY-040. If i use it, i  wouldnt need to activate arduino's built in pull up resistors right? I think Ky-040 has its own pull up resistors right?

Comment: KY-40 is a rotary switch on a small PCB with room at the back for pull-up resistors. If you are lucky they are present ;)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen what did you mean by present :D So they have pre soldered pull up resistors right?

Comment: @ÇayÖncesi: I am not familiar with the Ky-040. Some encoders are optical and they use a disc with transparent and black zones on them. These use LEDs and sensors to detect position and so never wear out - unlike your mechanical switch. The LEDs need +5 V and GND.