# Potentiometer like component

Tags: identification, potentiometer, volume

Okay you might get this a lot around here; I'm trying to figure out the inner workings of this specific potentiometer like component. I want to get my hands on the datasheet or a similar components datasheet.

It is used to change the volume of the device in question. Rolling is infinite in both directions, it has a small click. I tried measuring it's workings with the multi-meter but I'm baffled by its working.

One click in either direction shorts all three pins. The very next click measures a 620ohm between the three pins, along with a 3.2v between pin 3 and 1/2.

I'm a real noob on electrical engineering, never came across something like this.

[image: From left to right, pin 1-3]
[image][image]

Comment: The silk screen identifier 'SW2' gives a clue that it is a type of switch rather than a potentiometer.

Comment: +1 for the excellent photographs.

Comment: That's a co-incidence, I just took my mouse apart to clean mine up a bit.  It still sticks though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's a rotary encoder - not a potentiometer. The encoder pulses are sent to the microcontroller which adjusts the volume of the system.

[image]

*Figure 1. 2-bit rotary encoder waveforms. The relative phase of the signals indicates clockwise/anti-clockwise rotation and can be used by the controller to count up or down.*

Links:

- [How does a Rotary Encoder work without connecting it to 5V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222444/how-does-a-rotary-encoder-work-without-connecting-it-to-5v/222448#222448).
- [How do I get a position from an encoder?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227905/how-do-i-get-a-position-from-an-encoder/227936#227936)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It all made sense now!

Comment: @RicardoSnoek Does this answer not deserve to be marked as accepted?

Comment: It does! Just forgot to mark it :-)

Answer (score 12):

It's a rotary encoder, rather than a potentiometer. It looks like [this](https://www.kailhswitch.com/mouse-encoder/rotary-encoder/11mm-encoder-used-in-mouse186.html) may be your part, but you may need to contact them to get a datasheet.